# How to refresh Image.texture from CoreImage.texture?

Tags: image, python-2.7, kivy

I'm looking for a way to refresh camera miniature images from snapshots. I have this piece of code, but after first refresh (not the one in the reloadMiniatures thread) I get nothing (black screen).
I have tried other solutions but showing 6x mjpeg streams was to heavy (and I don't really need high framerate). Had some success with AsyncImage and saving images to file, but it wasn't very efficient and I had this loading_image to get rid of.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.image import Image
import time
import threading
import urllib
from kivy.core.image import Image as CoreImage
from io import BytesIO

class TestApp(App):
    def reloadMiniatures(self):
        while True:
            data = BytesIO(urllib.urlopen("http://10.0.13.206:9000/?action=snapshot").read())
            time.sleep(3)
            self.image.texture = CoreImage(data, ext='jpg').texture

    def build(self):
        data = BytesIO(urllib.urlopen("http://10.0.13.206:9000/?action=snapshot").read())
        self.image = Image()
        self.image.texture = CoreImage(data, ext='jpg').texture

        miniatures = threading.Thread(target=self.reloadMiniatures)
        miniatures.daemon = True
        miniatures.start()

        return self.image

TestApp().run()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using `Loader` instead:

```
def load_miniatures(self, *args):
    proxy = Loader.image('http://10.0.13.206:9000/?action=snapshot')
    proxy.bind(on_load=self.receive_miniatures)

def receive_miniatures(self, proxy):
    if proxy.image.texture:
        self.image.texture = proxy.image.texture
    Clock.schedule_once(self.load_miniatures, 0.1)

def build(self):
    self.image = Image()
    self.load_miniatures()
    return self.image
```

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't found a way to disable loader cache.
Without this it gets the image data from Cache and doesn't refresh it.
I've tried adding some random string to the url and it works but.. those loaded images stay in the memory so it won't work.

Disabling cache didn't change anything either:
    Cache._categories['kv.loader']['limit'] = 0 
    Cache._categories['kv.loader']['timeout'] = 0

Comment: proxy = Loader.image('http://10.0.13.206:9000/?action=snapshot', nocache=True)

This 'nocache=True' saved the day. It seems it's working in 1.9
Thans a lot! ;]